# How to install mbstring for PHP in Nitrous.io?

Tags: php, php-extension, nitrousio

How I can install the mbstring extension for PHP in Nitrous.io?

I want use phpMyAdmin, but have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in /home/action/workspace/www/phpMyAdmin/libraries/php-gettext/gettext.inc on line 177

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

```
$ cd ~
$ php -v # check php version, last time it was 5.5.8
$ svn export https://github.com/php/php-src/branches/PHP-5.5.8/ext/mbstring mbstring
$ cd mbstring
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make && make install
$ echo 'extension=mbstring.so' >> /home/action/.parts/etc/php5/php.ini
$ httpd -k restart # restart apache
$ php -c /home/action/.parts/etc/php5/php.ini -m | grep mbstring # check if the ext is loaded
```

Hope it helps.

The new php5 pack is compiled with mbstring support, just update your autoparts:

```
$ parts update
$ parts install php5
$ php -m | grep mbstring
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update PHP5 to get mbstring to work (the update as of 2/19/2014). Run these commands to update PHP5:

```
$ parts install php5
$ parts stop apache2
$ parts start apache2
```